# Xero API not working for Accounts in python

Tags: python, xero-api

I am trying to call xero Accounts api in python but not working for some reason. It works well for the rest of APIs such as Invoices, reports, and so on, but Accounts.

The following script is my python script i am using to call the api.

```
get_url = 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Accounts'   
response = requests.get(get_url,
                        headers = {
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                            'Xero-tenant-id': xero_tenant_id,
                            'Accept': 'application/json'
                        })
json_response = response.json()
print(json_response)
```

But this is throwing the following error:

```
{'Type': None, 'Title': 'Unauthorized', 'Status': 401, 'Detail': 'AuthorizationUnsuccessful', 'Instance': '3c1649ef-6eed-4e64-8503-04fc99481db2', 'Extensions': {}}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? why just Accounts?

Comment: The problem maybe you use wrong TenantID. Try call tenants API call first to get TenantID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share what scopes you're requesting? https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/scopes

Invoices requires `accounting.transactions`
Reports requires `accounting.reports.read`
Accounts requires `accounting.settings`

Comment: Yes, i forgot accounting.settings. It is working now. Thank you so much @Rett Behrens